# c# exception error when trying to retrieve url from webbrowser

Tags: c#, exception, browser

The current code I am using is

```
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.Url = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/user/RayWilliamJohnson");
        label1.Text = browser.Url.ToString();
```

but it is giving me a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' on the `label1.Text = browser.Url.ToString();` line. I don't know why it is doing this or how I can fix this and it is getting on my nerves so any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the debugger breaks for the exception, you can:

- hover over the variables in the editor, or
- look in the "Locals" debug window

to see what their values are. You should be able to easily see what is `null`. Then work your way up the call chain, and see where it was supposed to be initialized.

[image]

This is straightforward debugging that you will need to learn to do if you want to be a productive developer.

Comment: thanks turns out I did initialize it in the wrong place haha.